# Get value from Javascript object using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am having an issue getting accessing the value from a key of an object.

I am passing in `this.fields` which has 2 objects in an array like,

```
[{'First Name': 'firstName'}, {'Last Name': 'lastName'}]
```

I am able to get the keys using the `Object.keys` function, but cannot figure out how to get the values associated with them.

```
let properties = [];
for (let field of this.fields) {
  console.log(field);
  properties.push({
    "name": Object.keys(field),
    "value": ""
  });
}
```

I have tried doing `this.fields[field]` to get it, but it is returning undefined.  Any advice on how to approach this?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have 1 object with 2 keys instead of 1 array with 2 objects each one 1 key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let properties = [];
for (let field of this.fields) {
  for (let prop in field) {
    properties.push({ "name": prop, "value": field[prop] });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works, I am assuming that I needed the 2nd for loop to go over the object once it was taken out of the array.  Don't know why I didn't think of that!

Comment: Avoid `hasOwnProperty` when you don't need it. Your first version was much better.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one key/value pair, you can do:

```
let key = Object.keys(field)[0];
let value = field[key];
```